# My interactive rebase squash ends up with more commits instead of reducing them. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

I have a branch named `myBranch`, which I'm working on for a complex feature for a long time. After I finished my work and wanted to open a merge request, gitlab showed that 47 commits was done in my branch.

I thought the MR would be easier to understand if there was a single commit combining all the changes, because most of the individual commits were to try different things until it worked.

I heard about the term "squashing" before to combine multiple commits into one, so I decided that I could try and learn that.

I started with:

`git rebase -i HEAD~47`

It showed me a text file with a list of commits and choices like pick, squash or reword.

There were some old commits unrelated to my work in the text file, so I left them as "pick".
I typed "reword" for my first commit in the branch, and changed the commit message to the feature I'm adding with my branch.
I typed "squash" for the rest of them, up to the latest commit.

Then the rebase process continued. It stopped a few times for merge conflicts and asked me to fix then add them. I fixed the conflicts, added them using `git add -A` then continued with `git rebase --continue`.

After a few merge conflict fixes, process completed and I run `git push origin myBranch --force`, and tried to open a merge request using my branch.

Now it shows a whopping 101 commits, way more than my initial 47!

Instead of reducing the number of commits into 1, I actually increased them.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: No need for a rebase. Easiest thing is just to do a `git reset HEAD~47` which will keep the contents of your working directly but point you to the commit 47-ago. Then simply re-commit the work and you're done.

Comment: What would the merge request have looked like if you hadn't rebased? I mean, the fact that you've been working on this branch "for a long time", and you have evidently not merged main into this branch so it has not kept up with it, is suspect. Really, though, we'd need a lot more info in order to answer the question in detail, but my point is, I suspect that this has very little to do with the rebase (though note, please, that every commit that you did `pick` or `reword` is going to be a new commit — you were _never_ going to end up with just 1 commit on the merge request).

Comment: If your branch is not linear, 47 commits do not mean that you can pick `HAED~47` as the new base. The new base should be the merge-base of your branch and the target branch, which you can find by `git merge-base <your-branch> <target-branch>`.

Comment: @TooTone does that also work if I already pushed my changes to the remote branch?

Comment: @uylmz Yes, you'll need to do a `git push --force-with-lease` to have your single commit replace the 47, which you'd have done anyway with a rebase. Usual caveats about rewriting history apply, simply put only do it if you're sure you're the only person working on your branch.

Answer (score 1):

> After I finished my work and wanted to open a merge request, gitlab showed that 47 commits was done in my branch.

Make sure those 47 commits are all from your current work: I always prefer rebasing my branch on top of the target branch first:

```
git fetch
git switch my-feature-branch
git rebase origin/target-branch
```

That will force you to deal with any merge conflict locally.
And you can do a `git rebase -i origin/target-branch` instead, if you want to squash some commits (as noted by [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77581664/my-interactive-rebase-squash-ends-up-with-more-commits-instead-of-reducing-them#comment136772856_77581664), each `pick` or `reword` creates a *new* commit: an interactive rebase where multiple commits are picked or reworded will not necessarily reduce the number of commits to one).

Force push your branch (rebased on top of the target branch) and your merge request should be trivial.

Comment: I noticed something that I might did wrong. After I made changes in the history file during interactive rebase, I didn't save the file but just quit. I got used to text editors asking if I wanted to save it before quitting and since it didn't ask, I assumed it didn't need saving? Editor is `nano` btw.

Comment: @uylmz I am not familiar with nano, but I would still save before quitting, to be sure.  Ctrl + O before Ctrl + X.